# sudo: effective uid is not 0, is sudo installed setuid root?

Tags: raspbian, sudo

For a somewhat stupid reason I've run sudo chmod -R 777 /usr/bin and now get the error message. I know that I've broken my suso, but is there a way to fix it know what directory is involved?

Comment: Can you mount the SD card in another Linux system or with a Linux Live CD?  Do you have a root password on the Pi?

Comment: I have the root pw and I have access to the SD card from LinuxLind.

Comment: Have you tried logging on as root and changing the permissions back to 644 for /usr/bin?  For sudo additionally do chmod +s /usr/bin/sudo

Comment: Joan, how do I incorporate my original root password in these commands?

Comment: You need to login as root, e.g. use the command su, it will prompt you for the root password.  Then try what I suggested above.

Comment: I'm sorry for my ignorance, the root of the pi (because I tried that), or the root of LinuxMint - because I tried what you said with sudo, but it broke all my commands on Raspbian (had to change it all back to -777 again to start fresh from my initial mistake. I have root privileges with Mint without su.

Comment: I am only talking about the Pi.  It seems likely that the quickest solution will be to start again from scratch and reimage your Pi SD card.

Comment: I appreciate your help on this, but one last question. I mounted the sd card to Mint, and with command line ran the commands you gave above using sudo (i.e. these were now obviously using Mint's root/superuser changing the permissions back as suggested), but doesn't this mean that only Mint's superuser has access to these files - hence then inability to use any commands when putting the sd back in the pi?

Comment: No, the user Id and group Id are stored as numbers within the system.  The root user/group Id is universally 0.  So anything marked as owned by root wil be owned as root on all Linux systems.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32502/discussion-between-renier-delport-and-joan).